# Validation/Submission error: Application failed codesign verification

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing

I have a number of apps that are almost identical (with the exception of a few constants, images, and a sqllite database file). I've never had any issues submitting them before, however today one of the updates gave the following error when validating/submitting (note: I have updated this app in the past with no issues):

**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.**

I've spent all day trying everything to get this to work. I even diff'd the entire project folder against another app (which submitted successfully, today), and all build/signing settings are *exactly* the same (except bundle identifier, version number, etc.). I've even (as a last resort!) revoked the certificate and re-generated everything, including provisioning profiles.

I've been through all of the steps listed here:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933

However, if I "Share" the app from the Organizer and save to disk, running codesign -dvvv says it's not signed at all (however, this happens with the ones that worked!). Not sure how else to run this, as the file generated (and shown in Organizer) is not a .app file.

I'm at a total loss how to figure out what's wrong with this, or why it's any different to the others. I don't seem to be able to get any more information out of the Organizer. The app was built exactly the same way as the others, and the project files etc. are identical (except for expected differences like images/names).

Comment: Are you trying to submit to app store or just share via testflight or beta testing?

Comment: I'm just trying to submit an update to the store (via the Submit button in the Organizer, though the Validate button gives the same error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, fixed this... I wish I'd tried this sooner, as it would've saved me many hours today!

It seems that the App Store provisioning file for this app was somehow corrupt - not on my Mac, but on Apples servers.. I downloaded it *many* times today, with no luck. I just discovered that selecting the Ad-Hoc profile during Validation worked, which led me to believe it was specific to the App Store one. So I *deleted* the App Store provisioning file from the iOS dev dashboard, then recreated it, downloaded it, and it worked!

Before I deleted it, I edited it, and everything was set correctly, and the expiration date was 6 months from now, so I can only assume something was broken Apple's side (even though I'm sure this same file worked in the past!) :-(

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem. 
  All my provisioning Profiles, Certificates, Bundle Identifier every thing was perfect. 
 Except My Apps Executable file Name in Info.Plist and Product Name in Target Build Settings was slightly different. 
 And just because of that codesign_wrapper was not able locate Provisioning. 
I spend nearly one day to figure this out.

So Please do one check 
**App Product Name is have to be same with your Executable file in Info.Plist.**

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem, but in my case my distribution profiles keep disappearing from my system. So when an application specific distribution profile disappear Xcode picks up another one (wildcard, iPhone developer, etc.) which is not correct. Everything looks fine except I get this error.

My solution was that I downloaded all of my code signing profiles from Apple. I saved them in a directory and whenever one "disappears" I just have to double click the correct profile to add it to Xcode and update "release" entry in Code Signing Identity in plist.

Comment: I noticed all of mine disappear when ticking the automatic provisioning option, so I don't try that anymore :(